# C# - Convert MenuStrip code to ToolStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

I am trying to convert code that was originally meant for a MenuStrip to something that will work with a ToolStrip. In short, a MenuItem is passed on to Init() and I need to determine what the parent is of the menu item in question.  This snippet works fine with a MenuStrip, but I can't seem to get it working with a ToolStrip where the parent is a ToolStripDropDownButton.

Original Code Snippet (Ideal for MenuStrip):

```
private MenuItem menuItemMRU;
private MenuItem menuItemParent;

public void Init(MenuItem mruItem)
{
    menuItemMRU = mruItem;
    menuItemParent = (MenuItem) menuItemMRU.Parent;
}
```

This is what I've got so far

```
private ToolSTripMenuItem menuItemMRU;
private ToolStripDropDownButton menuItemParent;

public void Init(ToolStripMenuItem mruItem)
{
    menuItemMRU = mruItem;
    menuItemParent = (ToolStripMenuItem)menuItemMRU.Owner;
}
```

This gives me the following error:

Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem'

Comment: And what do you mean by `I can't seem to get it working with a ToolStrip`? An error/exception or some other behavior?

Comment: Updated question with what I'm currently attempting to use.

Comment: You get the error `Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem'`, because the `Owner` is type of `ToolStrip` and not `ToolStripMenuItem`.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense.  So how should I go about finding the parent of a ToolStripMenuItem since it doesn't have a "Parent" property like standard MenuItem does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToolStripItem` does however have an `OwnerItem` property. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.owneritem.aspx)