# SourceControl Null

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a `ContextMenuStrip`(called MenuPanels) with the idea of creating a right-click menu.
I have a `TableLayoutPanel`with a Matrix of Panels and I've added a `Mouse_Click`event to every panel, and then placed

```
if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
{
MenuPanels.Show(Cursor.Position);
}
```

as part of the event.

And in MenuPanels I've added a Delete option, the idea would be to change the backgroundImage of the panel.

I've read through a lot of other questions that focus on similar facts but haven't been able to get the Panel from with the `ContextMenuStrip` has been called, as the SourceControl returns null..

I've tried the methods in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886327/determine-what-control-the-contextmenustrip-was-used-on).

And also tried to get the SourceControl from the Opening event ([has suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534417/source-control-is-null-when-accessing-from-a-sub-context-menu-item-in-c-sharp)) but haven't been successful with that either..

[You can see the debug here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcwLW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `MouseClick` event to show the context menu. Instead, set the `ContextMenuStrip` property of the controls to the instance of the `ContextMenuStrip`. This will automatically show the context menu strip at the correct location and with the correct source control.

Comment: Ah Thanks @zohar-peled didn't know that that existed ;) Worked out great